# New mobile web theme doesn't highlight comments from the OP

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, mobile-web

On main and in the old mobile site (iirc) the username of the OP is highlighted in the comments.  This is no longer the case after the new design/theme was rolled out yesterday.

Can we get this back?

Comment: Case in point..

Comment: hey, thanks for reporting. i havent touched this section (at least intentionally) so im not sure why is that broken but i will investigate that. thanks again.

Comment: @Paweł it's totally possible it was never on the mobile site to begin with.. but I'm *pretty* sure it was.

Comment: @Pawel Was it fixed? On my mobile I see it correctly (but its an outdated browser)

Comment: It does look fixed. Sweet!

Comment: Yeap, it should be fixed now (hopefully):)

Comment: @Paweł Better, but the previous style had a lot better contrast. Currently, it's [1.71:1!](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=d58e10&bcolor=0077cc). The blue background used to be *much* darker.